# Ruby: Escape parenthesis in a string

Tags: ruby

I am doing a database query and want to escape parenthesis in the string, only if its returned in my query results, for example:

/This is a test string (2013)/

How do I do this?

Comment: What do you exactly mean by escaping? It is clear, for example, for tabs, but not for parentheses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create a Regexp with all special characters escaped, use

```
Regexp.new( Regexp.escape(str) )
```

I hope this is what you are trying to achieve.